# calling asset on production env didn't work Laravel 8 (shared hosting)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

hello there I'm having trouble with calling my asset in the production environment this is how the structure of the folder

- Laravel/

  - storage
  - ...
- public_html/

  - storage(a symlink that I created and working fine using, ln -sfn
    domains/sites.com/new/storage/app/public/posted-images/ ../public_html/)
  - ...

and this is how I call the asset :

```
   <img src="{{ asset('storage/'.$posts->image)  }}" alt="" class="img-fluid">
```

this is how my filesystem.php looks a like :

```
'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],

       'links' => [
        public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public'),
       ],
```

and in .env I put :

```
FILESYSTEM_DRIVER = public
```

Answer (score 1):

So I found the solution like this :
first I'm deleting the storage link that I created with ln -sfn domains/sites.com/new/storage/app/public/posted-images/ ../public_html/

then, in filesystem.php change :

```
'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```

to

```
'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => 'storage',
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```

after that, make a request to store function and it will create the storage folder in public_html. Your old file maybe not gonna appear there so(file before you change the root to 'storage'), you can copy the data that not there from storage folder in the domain.

And the way i call the asset is the same as above.